# how I can automate an app using another app?

Tags: android, automation, ui-automation

I have to build an app that just take some kind of information from user and then open another app and do some clicks on its own and fill that information which we have taken from the user on the designated field of the second app.
i have been trying to come up with some solution but cant actually figure out how it can be done.
is there any way it can be achieved?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Answer (score 0):

for launching another app you should use *PackageManager* in android and for sending data to another app, the destination app **must** enable this feature inside itself to receive your data(data send by intent to another app)

Comment: Can't I just have the automation package installed on my app that will fill the form inside another app?

Comment: definitely you cant

Comment: so what are the other options for me ? like all I want is to get the name from my user and fill the data automatically on that other app.

Comment: there is no option, just second app must let you